# From text to formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wan't to create a formula as a textstring from dynamically updated cells with a content of references to ranges in different sheets. This textstring needs then to be converted into a formula in another sheet. I guess I would be able to use the Evaluate function in excel. But in google spreadsheet this shouldn't work.
the textstring looks like this: `FILTER(DBD!B2:F;LÆNGDE(DBD!B2:B)>0)` and more filter references can be added.

```
{FILTER(DBD!B2:F;LÆNGDE(DBD!B2:B)>0);FILTER(DBDold!B2:F;LÆNGDE(DBDold!B2:B)>0);....}
```

As for now I've mannaged to get the code right with a script and the formula seems to be generated right. But it won't do the calculation until I manually either put in a space at the end or in other way make a change to the formular.

```
function addFormula(){
var formula = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Stamdata").getRange('E5').getValue();
var samlet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Samlet").getRange('B2');
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
samlet.setFormula(formula);
}
```

Stamdata!E5 is: `FILTER(DBD!B2:F;LÆNGDE(DBD!B2:B)>0)` (LÆNGDE=LEN in english)
In Samlet!B2 is created the formula `=FILTER(DBD!B2:F;LÆNGDE(DBD!B2:B)>0)`
just as it should - but the result is #I/T (`Fejl FILTER har forskellige intervalstørrelser. Forventede 249 rækker og 1 kolonner, men indeholder 1 rækker og 1 kolonner.` = in english something like FILTER has different size. Expected 249 rows og 1 column, but has 1 row and 1 column.)
If I in Samlet!B2 at the end of the new generated formula puts in a space everything is calculated correct.

I've then tried to make a simple formula in Stamdata!E5 like 3*3. Then the formula is created and calculated without any manually 'intervention'.

Comment: Could you share an example? I can't repeat this.

Comment: Here is a copy of the document - You can run the function in the menu "Refresh": https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1USA6WsoCX5GVb6MoTcDsJ7pvjqj5XfAqLOlAFJsPKgQ/edit#gid=0

Comment: I did manage to make it work with a query instead. But I got some weird results depending on the data and the link in the first row isn't active. I've copied the query formula in to Stamdata!E5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution: The formula needs to be a string that **includes an "equals" (=) prefix**.

Cell E5 presently contains a formula (=E4) which yields:

```
{FILTER(DBD!B2:F;LÆNGDE(DBD!B2:B)>0);FILTER(Platformen!B2:F;LÆNGDE(Platformen!B2:B)>0)
```

Two things to note here:
1) the content is treated as text
2) there is no "equals sign" (=) at the beginning of the string.

The content ***should*** look like this:

```
={FILTER(DBD!B2:F;LÆNGDE(DBD!B2:B)>0);FILTER(Platformen!B2:F;LÆNGDE(Platformen!B2:B)>0)
```

**How to fix it**

Edit Cell E5 (or Cell E4, whichever suits you) to insert an equals sign (=) to the left of the opening curly bracket. The result will still be treated as a string, so there is no danger involved ;)

*One proviso:* I had to convert "LÆNGDE" to "LEN" in order for my test to work. But I think this is probably just an issue of "Display Language" which, for me, is English (Australia), and for you is probably Danish.